# Breaking a function which return a list c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a function which returns a list of `treenodes`. I want to exit the `for` loop and exit the function and stop running program when the following `if` condition is not met.
I know for such a situation `return` works fine but here I have an error in the first `return` with the message.

> An object of a type convertible to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is required

My function:

```
public List<TreeNode> FindIndex(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<TreeNode> list)
{
    int idx;
    foreach (TreeNode Node in nodes)
    {
        if (Node.Text == "test")
        {
            idx = Node.Index;
            list.Add(Node);
        }
        else
        {
            bool isEmpty = !list.Any();
            if (isEmpty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This XML file does not contain any node with name \"test\"!");
                return;
            }
        }
        FindIndex(Node.Nodes, list);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I have tried the `break` but it does not stop program and will break only the function not running the whole code.

Comment: Eh, `return list;`? Or return an *empty* list, i.e. `return new List<TreeNode>()`;

Comment: on which line and what kind of error u r getting

Comment: Its also possible to return null.

Comment: Nobody seems to have mentioned this yet, but the `else` part should check if the list is empty before claiming that *this XML file does not contain any node with name "test"*...

Comment: @MatthewWatson very keen! ;)

Comment: This method doesn't even need to return a list, but maybe that's just because it's sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest redesigning your solution into

```
  // You're looking for nodes, not indexes, right?
  // Do you want to return the nodes or append the list? Let's return nodes
  public IEnumerable<TreeNode> FindNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes) {
    if (null == nodes)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("nodes");

    // providing that modes doesn't contain null nodes
    foreach (Treenode node in nodes)
      if (node.Text == "test")
        yield return node;
      else {
        // Your test message, comment out it in the release 
        MessageBox.Show("This XML file does not contain any node with name \"test\"!");

        yield break; // no more items 
      }
  }

...

  List<TreeNode> list = FindNodes(myNodes).ToList();
```

Technically, the method itself is an *overshoot*, and you can put just an easy and readable *Linq* query:

```
  List<TreeNode> list = nodes
    .OfType<TreeNode>()
    .TakeWhile(node => node.Text == "test")
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `break;` to exit the `foreach`

```
public List<TreeNode> FindIndex(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<TreeNode> list) {
int idx;
foreach (TreeNode Node in nodes)
{
    if (Node.Text == "test")
    {
        idx = Node.Index;
        list.Add(Node);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This XML file does not contain any node with name \"test\"!");
        break;
    }
    FindIndex(Node.Nodes, list);
}
return list;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this version but does not stop the whole program. :(

Comment: what you mean by stop whole program? Close the form? If so add `Close();` before `return list;`.

Comment: I mean stop running the code after showing the message.

Comment: It will stop after after returning from the function if you are not processing the result. Can you post the code of calling function?

Comment: here is: `List<TreeNode> IndexList1 = new List<TreeNode>();
            IndexList1 = FindIndex(treeView1.Nodes, IndexList1);
            indx1 = IndexList1[0].Index;`

Answer (score 0):

if u want to break the for loop

```
public List<TreeNode> FindIndex(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<TreeNode> list)
{
    int idx;
    foreach (TreeNode Node in nodes)
    {
        if (Node.Text == "test")
        {
            idx = Node.Index;
            list.Add(Node);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This XML file does not contain any node with name \"test\"!");
            return list;
        }
        FindIndex(Node.Nodes, list);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can exit application like this

```
   public List<TreeNode> FindIndex(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<TreeNode> list) {
    int idx;
    foreach (TreeNode Node in nodes)
    {
        if (Node.Text == "test")
        {
            idx = Node.Index;
            list.Add(Node);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This XML file does not contain any node with name \"test\"!");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        FindIndex(Node.Nodes, list);
    }
    return list;
    }
```

The above code will break the loop , exit the function and even stop the program.I must say not a graceful way to exit a program

Comment: But it will not stop the whole code, right? because when there is an empty list then in the next lines of code there would be an error.

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh What do you mean by whole code? Application Exit will exit /stop your whole Win form program

Comment: but it does not stop unfortunately!!

Comment: what do you mean by *there is an empty list then in the next lines of code there would be an error.*? Which line of code you are talking about? Did you debug and check if Applicaiton.Exit was called.

Comment: in the calling line: `List<TreeNode> IndexList1 = new List<TreeNode>(); IndexList1 = FindIndex(treeView1.Nodes, IndexList1); indx1 = IndexList1[0].Index;`

Comment: Application Exit will exit the whole program so calling code will also not get called..but if you still see that calling code is getting called then you have put Applicaiton.Exit in incorrect place and it is not even executing.

Comment: I think you should update exactly what you want to achieve in your question. Because my answer definitely answers *I have a function which returns a list of treenodes. I want to exit the for loop and exit the function and stop running program when the following if condition is not met.*

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method `Application.Exit` at any place in your code to immidiately stop the entire program. This way you don't have to return from the function and wait for all other code to execute.

See also the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx